# Python remove list elements

Tags: python, python-itertools

If I have a python list:

```
text = ["the", "red", "", "", "fox", "", "is"]
```

How can I use `itertools` (or another way) to modify the text list so that it checks `elem` and `elem+1` and if it finds equals to `""`, then it removes them from the list.  I only want the list modified if `elem + elemt1` are found (so the `["fox" "", "is"]` portion remains in the list).  Ordering of the list elements have to remain intact.

```
text = ["the", "red", "fox", "", "is"]
```

Comment: so you want to remove null values with "" from the list?

Comment: What about `["the", "red", "", "", "", "fox", "", "is"]`? Should all the three empty strings be removed or you keep one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

print list(chain(*[
    l for l in [list(it) for _, it in groupby(text)] if l[:2] != ['', '']
]))
```

Result:

```
['the', 'red', 'fox', '', 'is']
```

With `groupby` we can same consecutive elements as lists. Then we check for each list if it has length greater than two and all elements are the empty string. Then we keep what we want and we flatten the lists using `chain`.

Comment: use `zip_longest`

Comment: That result does not look like the desired result in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I really enjoyed going through everyone's solutions.  This in particular.  I did have a question about the chain(*[list]).  When you add the *, it flattens out [ [lista] ] to [ lista ].  Does this work for chain only, or is it a generic python ability?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

new = []
for item, group in itertools.groupby(text):
    group = list(group)
    if item != '' or len(group) == 1:
        new.extend(group)

>>> new
['the', 'red', 'fox', '', 'is']
```

Or a bit more efficient with `groupby`-function. One can use the fact that empty strings are considered `False` when cast to `bool`:

```
import itertools

new = []
for item, group in itertools.groupby(text, bool):
    group = list(group)
    if item or len(group) == 1:
        new.extend(group)

>>> new
['the', 'red', 'fox', '', 'is']
```

Comment: This is the same logic as my solution, but a lot more readable and, thus, instructive ;)

Answer (score 0):

it's  work with more than 2 white spaces also

```
text = ["the", "red", "","", "", "fox", "", "is"]
new_text = []

text_len = len(text);
print(text_len)
i = 0;
while(i < text_len):
    if (text[i] == "" and text[i + 1] == ""):
        i += 1;
        while(True):
                if (text[i] == "" and text[i + 1] == ""):
                    i+=1;
                else:
                        break;

    else :
        new_text.append(text[i]);
    i += 1;
print(new_text)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for t in text:
  if not t:
     text.remove(t)
```

Comment: never change a list you are iterating over.